# Create local repository for jar

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have main parent POM file which I use to declare all dependencies. I have 3 submaven projects. This is the file structure:

```
C:\NetBeansProjects\project\pom.xml
C:\NetBeansProjects\project\Core\System_Commons\pom.xml
C:\NetBeansProjects\project\Core\Tracking_Service\pom.xml
```

I need to use into my project weblogic client - wlfullclient.jar. I create local maven repository:

```
C:\NetBeansProjects\project\lib\com\weblogic\wlfullclient\10.3.6\wlfullclient-10.3.6.jar
C:\NetBeansProjects\project\lib\com\weblogic\wlfullclient\10.3.6\wlfullclient-10.3.6.pom
```

I added local repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>lib</id>
    <name>In Project Repo</name>
    <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
</repository>
```

Jar dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.3.6</version>
</dependency>

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\wlfullclient-10.3.6.jar -DgroupId=com.weblogic -DartifactId=wlfullclient -Dversion=10.3.6 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

But I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project System_Commons: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.project:System_Commons:bundle:1.0: Could not find artifact weblogic:wlfullclient:jar:10 at specified path C:\NetBeansProjects\project\Core\System_Commons\lib\wlfullclien
t-10.3.6.jar -> [Help 1]
```

The correct path should be here `C:\NetBeansProjects\project\lib\com\weblogic\wlfullclient\10.3.6\wlfullclient-10.3.6.jar`

Can you give me some idea how I can fix this?

Comment: If this project is shared between several developers than those libs belong to a repository manager and than you can use them as usual dependencies...So no need to make projekt libraries..

Comment: well currently I don't have a resources for central repository.

Comment: The repository manager (like Nexus) does not need very much resources...but makes life easier...

Answer (score 0):

there is not need to create a new repository (do you have any specific requirement?), you already have one, your local repository. The easiest thing to do is, to install this specific jar to your local repository. Usually that resides in the ~/.m2 folder (Mac/Unix) or  C:\Documents and Settings{your-username}.m2 for windows. See [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html).

So what you need to do is apply the following command :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=wlfullclient-10.3.6.jar 
                         -DpomFile=wlfullclient-10.3.6.pom 
                         -DgroupId=com.weblogic 
                         -DartifactId=wlfullclient 
                         -Dversion=10.3.6 
                         -Dpackaging=jar
```

In case though you want to have a separate 'local' lib repository you can use the following param on the example above :

```
-DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
```

See references [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html).

You can now reference your jar from your pom and and check of course your local report that the jar is indeed installed and the naming is correct.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes I need to create in-project repository because the project is shared between multiple developers

Comment: Have you tried the install above? Have you checked the contents of the wlfullclient-10.3.6.pom? Is the group and artifact id correct?